# stored procedure very slow, versus fast view with the same construction

Tags: sql, performance, stored-procedures, view, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure that was running very slowly for specific parameters.

The stored procedure returned a dataset.

I converted the stored procedure to a view.  I declared the same parameters and values and it returns the dataset in a couple seconds.

The stored procedure is taking five minutes.

I narrowed the problem down to a particular subquery in the stored procedure.  Removing the subquery enabled the stored procedure to return data immediately.  I converted the subquery to a temp table and joined the temp table rather than the subquery, and now the stored procedure returns data in a couple seconds.

The operations were identical in the initial view vs stored procedure test.  Is there something different about how a view is executed?

**Here is the stored procedure using the new temp table.  The original subquery is commented out:**

```
 (@JCCo bCompany,  
  @BegContract bContract ='', 
  @EndContract bContract ='zzzzzzzzzz', 
  @ThruMth bDate,
  @PM int = 0,
  @LabCTs varchar(10)=null,
  @MatCTs varchar(10)=null,
  @BegDept varchar(10) ='', 
  @EndDept varchar(10) ='zzzzzzzzzz')


With Recompile
as
--move the dates into a temp table
Select JCJM.JCCo, JCJM.Contract, JCCD.Job,
                        LastLaborDate=max(Case when JCTransType='PR' and (CostType between 2 and 3) then ActualDate else null end),
                        LastProjCostDate=max(Case when JCTransType='PF' then ActualDate else null end)
                    INTO #DATES
                   From JCCD JCCD with(NoLock)
                   Join JCJM JCJM with(nolock) on JCJM.JCCo=JCCD.JCCo and JCJM.Job=JCCD.Job
                    where (JCTransType='PR' or JCTransType='PF') and JCCD.JCCo=@JCCo and JCCD.Mth<=@ThruMth 
                            and JCJM.Contract Between @BegContract and @EndContract
                    group by JCJM.JCCo,JCJM.Contract,JCCD.Job
      -- ) as Dates on j.JCCo=Dates.JCCo and j.Contract=Dates.Contract and j.Job=Dates.Job




Select  JCCD.JCCo, JCCD.Job, JobDesc=j.Description, b.Contract, ContrDesc=b.Description, 

    --  MAX(Dates.LastLaborDate) as maxLastLaborDate, MAX(Dates.LastProjCostDate) as maxLastProjCostDate, 
    TD.LastLaborDate, TD.LastProjCostDate, 
--      '01/01/2013' AS LastLaborDate, '01/01/2015' AS LastProjCostDate,

        JCCD.Mth, JCCD.Phase, PhsDesc=JCJP.Description, 
        JCCD.CostType, CTDesc=JCCT.Description, JCCT.JBCostTypeCategory, 
        FieldPctCompl=isnull(u.PctCompl,0), FieldDate=Max(u.Date),  PMName=p.Name, 
        EstHours=sum(EstHours), EstCost=sum(EstCost), JTDHrs=sum(ActualHours), JTDCost=sum(ActualCost),
        ProjHours=sum(JCCD.ProjHours), ProjCost=sum(JCCD.ProjCost),
        MTDHrs=sum(case when JCCD.Mth=@ThruMth then ActualHours else 0 end), 
        MTDCost=sum(case when JCCD.Mth=@ThruMth then ActualCost else 0 end),
        FActCost=SUM(Case when JCCO.ProjMethod=2 then JCCD.ActualCost+JCCD.RemainCmtdCost else JCCD.ActualCost end),
        b.Department, DeptDesc=d.Description, HQName=HQCO.Name,ContrStat=b.ContractStatus,UIAmt=0,UITaxAmt=0,UIMiscAmt=0,ToBeInvd=0,sumTotalCmtdCost=0

from JCCD JCCD with(NoLock)
Left Outer Join JCJM j with(NoLock) on JCCD.JCCo=j.JCCo and JCCD.Job=j.Job
Left Outer Join JCCM b with(NoLock) on j.JCCo=b.JCCo and j.Contract=b.Contract
Left Outer Join JCDM d with(noLock) on b.JCCo=d.JCCo and b.Department=d.Department
Left Outer Join JCMP p with(NoLock) on j.JCCo=p.JCCo and j.ProjectMgr=p.ProjectMgr
Left Outer Join JCJP JCJP with(NoLock) on JCCD.JCCo=JCJP.JCCo and JCCD.Job=JCJP.Job and JCCD.Phase=JCJP.Phase
Left Outer Join JCCT JCCT with(NoLock) on JCCD.PhaseGroup=JCCT.PhaseGroup and JCCD.CostType=JCCT.CostType

Left Outer Join (Select u.Co, Job=u.Contract/*Prints Job# 9/13 per Tina - - VU9148*/, JCJM.Contract,
                        u.Phase, u.CostType, a.Mth, 
                        Date=Max(isnull(Date,'1950-01-01')),PctCompl=isnull(PctCompl,0)
                  from udVPPctComplete u
                  Join JCJM on u.Co=JCJM.JCCo and u.Contract=JCJM.Job
                  Join (select Co, Job=a.Contract,Contract=JCJM.Contract, Phase, CostType, Mth=Max(isnull(Mth,'1950-01-01')) 
                          from udVPPctComplete a 
                          Join JCJM on a.Co=JCJM.JCCo and a.Contract=JCJM.Job
                          where Mth<=@ThruMth and Co=@JCCo and JCJM.Contract between @BegContract and @EndContract
                          group by Co, a.Contract,JCJM.Contract, Phase, CostType
                     )a on a.Co=u.Co and a.Job=u.Contract and a.Phase=u.Phase and  a.CostType=u.CostType and a.Mth=u.Mth and a.Contract=JCJM.Contract
                group by u.Co, u.Contract,JCJM.Contract, u.Phase, u.CostType, a.Mth, isnull(PctCompl,0)
    ) u on JCCD.JCCo=u.Co and b.Contract=u.Contract and JCCD.Phase=u.Phase and JCCD.CostType=u.CostType and u.Job=JCCD.Job

    LEFT OUTER JOIN #DATES TD ON  j.JCCo=TD.JCCo and j.Contract=TD.Contract and j.Job=TD.Job
--Left Outer Join (Select JCJM.JCCo, JCJM.Contract, JCCD.Job,
--                      LastLaborDate=max(Case when JCTransType='PR' and (CostType between 2 and 3) then ActualDate else null end),
--                      LastProjCostDate=max(Case when JCTransType='PF' then ActualDate else null end)
--                 From JCCD JCCD with(NoLock)
--                 Join JCJM JCJM with(nolock) on JCJM.JCCo=JCCD.JCCo and JCJM.Job=JCCD.Job
--                  where (JCTransType='PR' or JCTransType='PF') and JCCD.JCCo=@JCCo and JCCD.Mth<=@ThruMth 
--                          and JCJM.Contract Between @BegContract and @EndContract
--                  group by JCJM.JCCo,JCJM.Contract,JCCD.Job
--     ) as Dates on j.JCCo=Dates.JCCo and j.Contract=Dates.Contract and j.Job=Dates.Job

Join JCCO JCCO with(NoLock) on JCCD.JCCo=JCCO.JCCo
Join HQCO HQCO with(NoLock) on JCCD.JCCo=HQCO.HQCo

where  JCCD.JCCo=@JCCo and b.Contract/*=' 51431.'--*/ between @BegContract and @EndContract and JCCD.Mth<=@ThruMth 
        and b.Department>=@BegDept and b.Department<=@EndDept 
        and j.ProjectMgr=(case when @PM<>0 then @PM else j.ProjectMgr end)

        and (charindex(','+left(cast(JCCD.CostType as char(5))+'     ', len(convert(varchar, JCCD.CostType)))+',', ','+@LabCTs+',')<>0 
                or charindex(','+left(cast(JCCD.CostType as char(5))+'     ', len(convert(varchar, JCCD.CostType)))+',', ','+@MatCTs+',')<>0 )
Group by JCCD.JCCo, JCCD.Job,j.Description, b.Contract, b.Description, JCCD.Mth, JCCD.Phase, JCJP.Description, JCCD.CostType,
            u.PctCompl,JCCT.Description, p.Name,JCCT.JBCostTypeCategory,
                    TD.LastLaborDate, TD.LastProjCostDate, 

            --Dates.LastLaborDate, Dates.LastProjCostDate,
            b.Department, 
            d.Description,HQCO.Name,b.ContractStatus
```

Comment: Please show us both codes.

Comment: Obviously the view and the stored procedure are not acting the same way, although they may produce the same result. Subselects are ... difficult: they may be executed for each resulted row. And please provide SQL statement and procedure code.

Comment: My guess is parameter sniffing. SQL Server determines the execution plan for a procedure the first time it is run, based on the params used. That plan is then cached and reused. With a view, the plan is generated for the ``select`` statement you run that references the view. The two could be completely different.

Comment: edited to show revised stored procedure including the commented-out subquery

Comment: If you are still investigating the poor prior performance, you could examine if the columns used in the subselect (max) are indexed or not.

Answer (score 1):

IF both queries are **literally** the same then you probably have a corrupted query plan cached in your stored procedure.

You can force the procedure to recompile the plan each time by adding `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to the procedure.

[Kim Tripp on OPTION(RECOMPILE)](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/using-the-option-recompile-option-for-a-statement/)

> If I know that a particular statement wildly varies from execution to execution and the optimal plan varies (again, I should know this from testing multiple sample executions), then I'll create the stored procedure normally and I'll use OPTION (RECOMPILE) to make sure that the statement's plan is not cached or saved with the stored procedure. On each execution that stored procedure will get different parameters and the particularly nasty statement will get a new plan on each execution.

**EDIT** I see, now, that you are calling a recompile. I'm going to leave this answer here, though for other searchers because it may be relevant to them.

Comment: Yes they are literally the same and I expected execution to be the same.  I think the stored procedure must have been doing a row-by-row evaluation for the Dates information.